# SwiftUI pass overlay content to parent views

Tags: swift, swiftui

`MainView` and `AnotherMainView` contain names arrays. They iterate over these arrays and both use the `DetailView` to show the name with some additional content. `MyViewModel` provides some functionalities such as adding a name etc. These should be triggered from a `DetailOverlayView` which uses the selected name for the actions (please see code comments.

My problem is, starting an overlay within the `DetailView` results in a very small overlay within the `DetailView` "cell" which is not what I want. This is why I would like to show it on the parent view. Unfortunately, I don't know how to pass the `DetailOverlayView` to the `MainView` and `AnotherMainView`. I tried with bindings or environment but this did not work. I would like to avoid redundancy such as defining overlays in both parent views etc.

Alternatively, maybe there is a solution to call it from the DetailView, but bypassing the detail view frame without giving some hardcoded height and width values.

```
struct MainView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: MyViewModel
    var names = ["aaa", "ccc", "ddd", "gght"]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(names, id: \.self, content: { name in
                DetailView(name: name).environmentObject(viewModel)
            })
        }///.overlay(... ->  need DetailOverlayView here
    }
}

struct AnotherMainView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: MyViewModel
    var names = ["bbb", "hhh"]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(names, id: \.self, content: { name in
                DetailView(name: name).environmentObject(viewModel)
            })
        }///.overlay(... ->  need DetailOverlayView here
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: MyViewModel
    @State var name: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Name of the user: ")
            Text(name)
        }///.overlay(... ->  this would show an DetailOverlayView as a part of this small DetailView and in its bounds which is not what I want
    }
    
    struct DetailOverlayView: View {
        @Binding var name: String ///this is the same name that the DetailView has, not sure if binding makes sense here
        @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: MyViewModel
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    viewModel.addName(name: name)
                }, label: {
                    Text("Add name")
                })
                Button(action: {
                    viewModel.doSomething1(name: name)
                }, label: {
                    Text("doSomething1")
                })
                Button(action: {
                    viewModel.doSomething2(name: name)
                }, label: {
                    Text("doSomething2")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    func addName(name: String) {
        ///
    }
    func doSomething1(name: String) {
        ///
    }
    func doSomething2(name: String) {
        ///
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want this overlay the size of the `VStack` showing _all_ the names (if you applied it to normally `MainView`), or do you want it to fill the screen / as much space as it can?

Comment: Also, do you need `@EnvironmentObject`? Or was that just to try solve the problem, and can use `@ObservedObject` instead? The latter would be the better option, but if you need `viewModel` thought the view hierarchy, it's fine to keep it. I was just wondering whether it was necessary.

Comment: Final thing... since `MainView` and `AnotherMainView` are practically the same view, why don't you just have one but with a different `names` array input?

Comment: 1. I want it to take as much space as it would need for these 3 buttons. 2. @EnvironmentObject is needed 3. This is just a minimum working example, the actual views are quite different, but both use the DetailView

Comment: Thank you, that's useful information. Doing an `overlay` in `DetailView` where you said gives my [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmMxc.png). I did increase the `VStack` spacing just because otherwise it would look like an overlapped mess. Is this what you are looking for?